# Upgrade restart fail

Tags: upgrade, data-recovery, restart, c

Upgrading from v13.04 to 13.10, all went well until "restart to complete"--screen did not come up for restart (Nvidia GeforceGTX650). I tried various suggestions, but now cannot get even Grub menu on screen.  I can see files (at least some) from a networked computer (shared directory), or from a live DVD of Linux Mint (I can't get a screen using Ubuntu some live DVDs).   I thought I could just copy data files to an external drive or networked computer, but I don't have permissions.   Can I install from a live DVD next to existing (but screwed up) OS (dual boot)? Would that be any help if I can?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the files and copy them using any linux live dvd.

1. Become root. `sudo su` usually works
2. mount the source and destination drives
3. copy the files

Yes, you can install from a live DVD next to an existing OS but I don't recommend it without a backup. One mistake and you could wipe your precious data away. Better to copy the files off first. If you have permissions difficulty that becoming root doesn't solve, look into chown to take ownership or chmod to allow access (both available on all distributions AFAIK).